# SQL Query question

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have this query to show

there are 2 tables, i will get the number of renovation from the table renovation while the customer-id and name is from table 1, customer.

[image]

```
SELECT c.[Customer-ID], c.name, COUNT(*)"Number of Renovation"
FROM CUSTOMER c, RENOVATION r
WHERE c.[Customer-ID] = r.[Customer-ID]
GROUP BY c.[Customer-ID], c.name
HAVING Count(*) in 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RENOVATION GROUP BY [Customer-ID])
ORDER BY c.[customer-id]
```

this is not the right way for me to do the query, anybody know how to shorten the query ? or the other ways of doing it ? though it still find the answer. i'm learning SQL server by the way.

Comment: i wanna list the customers and the number of renovation they have. i wanna use subquery but not sure if i'm doing the right thing.

Comment: the Having clause works similarly to the Where clause except it's attached to the Group By clause. Since there is no limiting condition in the requirements, there is no need for a Having clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, so you want customers and the renovations they have - why not just use :

```
SELECT c.[Customer-ID], c.name, COUNT(*) AS 'Number of Renovations'
FROM dbo.CUSTOMER c
INNER JOIN dbo.RENOVATION r ON c.[Customer-ID] = r.[Customer-ID]
GROUP BY c.[Customer-ID], c.name
```

I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve with the `HAVING COUNT(*) IN......` part of your query......

If you want to have all customers that have at least one renovation - try this:

```
SELECT c.[Customer-ID], c.name, COUNT(*) AS 'Number of Renovations'
FROM dbo.CUSTOMER c
INNER JOIN dbo.RENOVATION r ON c.[Customer-ID] = r.[Customer-ID]
GROUP BY c.[Customer-ID], c.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

Comment: i see, that is how short is can be, it works !!!! thanks Marc_s.
i will thinking that the HAVING clause is used to find if there is a value before i did the next step.

Answer (score 3):

The `HAVING` clause does not seem to belong here.  `HAVING` is intended to filter out resulting groups based on the aggregate result.  For example, you could use the HAVING clause to exclude records that do not have any renovations:

```
SELECT c.[Customer-ID], c.name, COUNT(*) AS [Number of Renovations]
FROM dbo.CUSTOMER c
INNER JOIN dbo.RENOVATION r ON c.[Customer-ID] = r.[Customer-ID]
GROUP BY c.[Customer-ID], c.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

Comment: Since @marc_s posted the same answer above — and nearly identical code — he should get the votes.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend the `HAVING` keyword for newbies, it is [essentially for legacy purposes](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/HAVING-A-Blunderful-Time.html).

The following is more verbose but could be easier to understand and therefore maintain (I've used a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) for the table `CUSTOMER_RENOVATION_TALLIES` but it could be a [`VIEW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) :

```
WITH CUSTOMER_RENOVATION_TALLIES ("Customer-ID", Tally)
     AS
     (
      SELECT [Customer-ID], COUNT(*) AS Tally
        FROM RENOVATION
       GROUP 
          BY [Customer-ID]
     )
SELECT c."Customer-ID", c.name, r.Tally
  FROM CUSTOMER AS c
       INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_RENOVATION_TALLIES AS r
          ON c."Customer-ID" = r."Customer-ID";
```

If you want to include a tally of zero for customers without renovations then `UINON` this set to the above resultset e.g.

```
WITH CUSTOMER_RENOVATION_TALLIES ("Customer-ID", Tally)
     AS
     (
      SELECT [Customer-ID], COUNT(*) AS Tally
        FROM RENOVATION
       GROUP 
          BY [Customer-ID]
     )
SELECT c."Customer-ID", c.name, r.Tally
  FROM CUSTOMER AS c
       INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_RENOVATION_TALLIES AS r
          ON c."Customer-ID" = r."Customer-ID"
UNION 
SELECT c."Customer-ID", c.name, 0 AS Tally
  FROM CUSTOMER AS c
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT * 
                     FROM CUSTOMER_RENOVATION_TALLIES AS r
                    WHERE c."Customer-ID" = r."Customer-ID"
                  );
```

Comment: I disagree with your statement that "it is essentially for legacy purposes" and even more with the article you linked to which says that "`HAVING` means exactly the same as `WHERE`, but has different rules concerning what can be written in the condition that follows it and in the `SELECT` clause that physically precedes it."  There is a very important difference between `WHERE` and `HAVING` that makes `HAVING` useful for more than just "legacy purposes": `WHERE` filters records before grouping is applied, and `HAVING` applies filtering on the aggregates _after_ grouping is applied.

Comment: The fact that they do different things necessitates the different terminology; how much **more** confusing would it be if both criteria operators were called `WHERE`?

Comment: @Boris Nikolaevich: it could be you missed the main point i.e. quote "if only the System R team had realized that their language was relationally incomplete without support for derived tables in the FROM clause, then they (and after them, Larry Ellison with his Oracle that brought SQL to the unsuspecting public at large) might have included such support and thus allowed their users... not to have to learn HAVING." Of course, it could be that you understand fully yet hold a different opinion, which is fine by me :)

Comment: @Boris Nikolaevich: BTW no one, AFAIK, is proposing that `WHERE` clause should be "filtering on the aggregates" within the same scope. The point is the `HAVING` came about because SQL didn't allow nested queries and  `HAVING` couldn't (and never can) be subsequently removed due to compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try following query,

```
select table1.id,table1.name,renovation .mobile_no from table1,renovation where table1.id=renovation.id
```